# コード４行目～６行目でｗを使っているのはどのような意図がありますか？

Tags: python

```
def median(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)
    if x > y:
       w = x
       x = y
       y = w
    print(x, y, z)
    if z < x:
         return x
    if z < y:
       return z
    return y
assert median(3, 1, 2) == 2
```

Comment: python ではその3行を `x, y = y, x` と書くことができるのですが、このコードを作成した人はその事を知らなかったのでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その式は「xとｙを入れ替える」という認識で間違いありませんか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。

Comment: 余談になりますが、この `median()` 関数は `def median(x, y, z): return sorted([x, y, z])[1]` と書くこともできます。

Answer (score 1):

```
if x > y:
  w = x
  x = y
  y = w
```

こちらのコードは`x`が`y`よりも大きい場合に、`x`と`y`を入れ替えています。（関数`median`の第一引数と第二引数が昇順に並ぶように処理しています）